# Injecting server-side meta tags into React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express, meta-tags

I am trying to change meta tags server-side depending on some database object's properties. The problem is that I can't really use EJS or any other templating engine because JavaScript bundle on production is generated in chunks and I have no access to their names while writing the template (main HTML file is also generated during build and it includes those chunks' names)

I've considered loading the build HTML as string using

```
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'path_to_html'), 'utf-8')
```

and manually replacing the meta tags, however there must be some other, more standard way to do this as this seems like a common problem.

I'd love to hear some suggestions or reasons why the above is bad idea.